# Converting decimal number into ascii in java

Tags: java, android

I want to break a decimal number and then convert it to ASCII format so that i can view it in text View.

I am getting Battery percentage from a device as decimal.I cant display it directly by passing decimal number, but need to pass ASCII to the text View.

For Eg: 
I am getting data in a byte array;
consider arr[7] has value 98 which means battery is 98%
I want to display the value 98 so i need to pass it as
0x39 and 0x38 respectively How can i break 98 into 0x39 and 0x38 respectively.
I tried by doing bitwise ending with 0x0f and 0xf0  and then added 0x30 but it gave me wrong value.

Comment: `I want to break a decimal number and then convert it to ASCII format` Why don't you convert it to a string, directly? i.e.: 10.5 => "10.5". The easiest way (not the more efficient one, though) to do that is simply appending an empty string to a number: `String myString = myNumber + "";`

Comment: 98 is still `int a = 98 / 10`; int `b = 98 - (a*10);`

Comment: @Blackbelt U solved mine problem in a very simple way. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.valueOf(byte)` to get the string representation of the byte.

If you must have ASCII representation, you can use the `toCharArray()` method in `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String hexValue = Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt("98"));
```

Then you can spilt it by " "

```
String[] splited = hexValue.split(" ");
```

Now you can get `splited[0] = 0x39` and `splited[1] = 0x38`